# Need help finding \t characters in C code. Currently stuck in the beginning of my while loops

Tags: c

I am trying to write code to find `'\t'` characters in a text file. Here is my current code. I am stuck in the `while` loop and continuously printing `Testing for while loop`. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void filter(int);  //Function prototype.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { //Main takes in argument count and argument value.
    printf("Number of arguments: %d\n", argc); //Print number of arguments for debugging.

    int charToReplace = 9; //Ascii value of tab.
    int numSpaces = 8; //Spaces per column.
    int inChar = getchar();
    int charCount = 0;

    if (argc == 2 || argc > 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid arguments given.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (argc == 3) {
        numSpaces = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    while (inChar != -1) { //We're not at a subtract, or end of file
        printf("Testing for while loop");
        if (inChar == 9) { //If we're at a tab
            printf("Testing for tab");
            inChar = 46; //Change it to a period
            for (int i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) { //Loop through 8 spaces.
                putchar(inChar); //Output a period.
            }//For loop
        }//If tab
    }//While not at the end
}//Main
```

Comment: You need to use getChar() again inside the while loop?

Comment: @MFerguson I assign inChar to getchar(), I believe that it should then act as getchar() throughout? Ill try it though.

Comment: "I assign inChar to getchar(), I believe that it should then act as getchar() throughout?" No, C doesn't work this way.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. What is 46? The comma character is spelled with the comma character: `','`. Likewise the tab is spelled `'\t'`, not `9`. The end of file indicator is spelled `EOF`, not `-1`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Im under the impression that 9 = \t, EOF = -1, and period = 46. When we observe those those through getchar() we are looking for ASCII values?

Comment: Do not use these observations in source code.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the initial `getchar()` and change the main loop to

```
while ((inChar = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Note also that the TAB expansion is incorrect, the number of spaces depends on the current column, which is reset to `0` at the end of line.